# SQL Like Operator not working as expected in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-like

I am trying to fetch all the data from the database with a certain content `tags` value. If I run the code below, it only returns the row with `id` 1, even though the word `tag` is part of the `tags` value in both rows. I also added `%or%` operator but it is fetching the exact row.  When I search for `tag` it is showing 2 rows, but using the value in `$mytags` below, it match es only 1 row.

I want the expression to get a row if anything in `$mytags` matches.

**SQL**

```
$mytags = "tag, tag1";
SELECT * FROM table WHERE tags LIKE '%$mytags%' ORDER BY id DESC
```

| id | body | tags |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Loreum Content 1 | tag, tag1 |
| 2 | Loreum Content 2 | tag |

Comment: You should post your actual code, not a pseudocode.

Comment: are you wanting both rows based off of a match on `tag` or one row based off of a match on `tag, tag1`?

Comment: If both `tags` column and `$mytags` variable may contain CSV tags list then LIKE operator is not applicable. Either parse one of them to separate values and test each value separately or use another technique (in MySQL - for example, convert these values to JSON using string finctions then use JSON_OVERLAPS() function).

Comment: Fix your data model!  It is broken if you are storing multiple values in a string column.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve your problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expectation of how `LIKE` works seems to be wrong. If you want those lines selected that match any of your comma separated tags in the `$mytags` variable, you need to do this in a different way.

If you wanted to use `LIKE` you would need to expand and use `OR`:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE tags LIKE '%tag%' OR tags LIKE '%tag1%' ORDER BY id DESC
```

But a better way to achieve this for a variable number of tags is using `REGEXP`:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE tags REGEXP 'tag|tag1' ORDER BY id DESC
```

All you need to do for that is change your separator in `$mytags` to `|` (no spaces):

```
$mytags = 'tag|tag1'
```

Comment: your `REGEXP` Worked perfact with variable, I replaced comma to `|` and it worked. Thanks